# WCF Recommended pattern for returning failure messages

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, response

I'm writing a WCF Service, and was wondering if there is a recommended pattern for returning various messages from a service method.

For example, if I call the `public User Login(string userName, string passWord)` method in my service, I want it to return my user object when they are valid users. However, if the details are not correct, or the account is disabled, I want to be able to return that data to the client.

I initially thought I would throw a `LogonFailureException` (custom exception class) when one of these two scenarios occurred. In the client, I could then catch this type and process it as I wanted. However, if I'm debugging the application, it breaks when the exception is thrown (even if I wrap it in a FaultException).

I could also create a `ServiceResponse` class that all my methods use as a return type - in there I could then have a "Messages" collection, but that seems potentially counter-intuitive. I'd rather the returntypes of my methods were simply what I expect to get back in normal circumstances.

So, bottom line, is there a particular pattern of dealing with messages coming back from the service method that is recommended?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with a `ServiceResponse` class that provides an error property for you to evaluate.

Comment: We use a similar system at work, and you are right, it works - but it sometimes feels like it's another layer of abstraction around the return value, when there might be a better and more efficient manner of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to throw a [strongly-typed soap fault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx):

```
[DataContract]
public class ConnectionFault
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Issue { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Details { get; set; }
}


[FaultContract(typeof(ConnectionFault))]
[FaultContract(typeof(DataReaderFault))]
[OperationContract]
Int16 GetInStock(int productId);

//when it's time to throw the exception
var connectionFault = new ConnectionFault();
connectionFault.Issue = "Problem connecting to the database";
connectionFault.Details = ex.Message;
throw new FaultException<ConnectionFault>(connectionFault);
```

Then the client can catch it.

Comment: I tried doing that in my method: for instance, I check the user IsEnabled property and, if the value is false, throw a new `FaultException<LoginFailureException>`, but when debugging, it breaks there instead of falling down to the client (which has a catch looking for it)

Comment: maybe it is a debug config in VS. w/o debugging do you get expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, There are 2 scenarios.
1. You wish to throw a sort of exception on the Service side.
2. You wish to return a class that contains error data of something went wrong in Service.

What is the difference ? The first would be just like yaron wrote, you throw and catch a FaultException.
The second would be just to return an object, for example if something went wrong in your service, you always return ErrorData - this is a data contract that contains message and exception stack as string - you can add ErrorData.Update method, and every time you catch a new exception in service, update the ErrorData message.. this is good for long running calls that might catch several exception but you dont want to abort on the first one.

No matter which of these you choose, **DO NOT INHERIT** from Exception, I have read this is bad practice, you dont want to serialize and transfer Exception based data contracts over WCF.